# More sessions created in oracle db

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

From Web Logic Data Source, i created data-source connection to Oracle DB with max 2 connection pools. My Project have 45 Spring Boot Rest services, when i am running these services using postman collection i can see multiple session ids are created in oracle db with my system name.

I am viewing the sessions that are created in Oracle using Oracle Sql Developer monitor sessions.

I have mentioned max connection pools as 2, why so many sessions created in oracle with my system name

Comment: Is your Spring Boot app really using the datasource?

Comment: Yes, the services are running

Comment: And you have configured Spring Boot to use the datasource or does Spring Boot maybe create its own datasource?

Comment: I have configured my spring boot application to use data source available in weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your maxPoolSize and configure the idle and life time of your db sessions. This may help you:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hikari